# Finding element using tagname and text (CSS)

Tags: css-selectors, shadow-root

We have taken over support for an organization in the company who gets a new release once a year.  We did not write the original code.

I entered a name in a search box and got a couple of options (see picture 1).  This gives me html as in picture 2.  Since I am finding this from a shadow root I need to do findElement(By.cssSelector) rathe than By.xpath().  [Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqKT4.png)  [image: Picture 2]

Previous code was using  "mark[.='Anthony Chamberlain']".  I do not know whether this works or not.  If I use just " mark" as a CSS selector it works fine but will pick the first one, which could be OK or might not.  I have tried " mark[.='Anthony Chamberlain']",
"mark[ innerText='Anthony Chamberlain'] and " mark[textContent='Anthony Chamberlain']" (I put a space before the mark to do recursive search.

The one where I use ".=" gives me an invalid selector error.  The other two just time out and cannot find the element (but the selectors are valid).  I have done google searches but am still not clear what to do.  If I could use xpath it would be ".//mark[.='Anthony Chamberlain']", but I can't.

Any suggestions of what to do?  I would even more like to find the div above it
(such as "//div[./mark[. = 'Anthony Chamberlain']]")

I am not sure I correctly uploaded picture 1, but it is an input field with matching selections underneath.

What is the correct css locator? Remember, simply " mark" works fine.

Comment: Why the java tag? There is no Java code or issue in the question.

Comment: you can not select text-nodes with CSS. If you want to work with text-nodes one option is JavaScript and the TreeWalker API

Comment: ``shadow-root (open)`` tells us a Web Component was used to create all this HTML. Thus the Web Component created that tag ``<mark`` tag and its contents, thus the Web Component can set that text **as attribute** on the ``<mark textContent="..."``. Contact the person who programmed this Web Component

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use css selector to test against node content.

See here for complete documentation : https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/

If you want to get your `mark` node, you can use the `mark[class*="has-highlight"]` css-selector according to the documentation mentioned above. You can then test in `js` if the `result.innerText` === 'Anthony Chamberlain'

> E[foo*="bar"] syntax : an E element whose foo attribute value contains the substring bar

Comment: since there is a div above it I am getting the div from CSS selector, and then using an xpath from it to find the mark

Comment: Could you be more precise of how you do it ?